# Mass Find/Replace

Tags: excel, replace, ms-word, office-automation

I'm tying to write a Macro to automatically find and replace words in a MS-word doc (800+ words) using an Excel database. Yet when I tell it to open the excel sheet I get Run-time error '1004': Excel cannot access 'Documents' (the folder where my spreadsheet is). Here's the macro I'm using (which I found here):

```
Function findAndReplace()

Dim xlApp As Object

Dim xlWB As Object

Dim xlWS As Object

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

Dim lastRow As Integer

'Set Objects
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...\Documents")
        'Replace String with path to Excel File
   
Set xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets("Word list for Macro")
        'Replace String with your Worksheet Name
    
'get last row of excel file
lastRow = xlWS.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'loop through all words in Word Document
For i = 1 To ThisDocument.Words.Count - 1 Step 1

'Loop through cells in Excel File
For j = 1 To lastRow Step 1

'Replace Word value in Column B of Excel File
ThisDocument.Words(i) = Replace(ThisDocument.Words(i), xlWS.Cells(j, 1).Value, xlWS.Cells(j, 2).Value)
    
Next j

Next i

'Close Excel and Cleanup

Set xlWS = Nothing

xlWB.Close True

Set xlWB = NothingxlApp.Quit

Set xlApp = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Here are two commercial tools:  https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/104-kutools-for-word/kutools-for-word-news-and-updates/5627-word-batch-find-and-replace.html and https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/104-kutools-for-word/kutools-for-word-news-and-updates/5627-word-batch-find-and-replace.html  I don't know how much your time is worth, but one of those is selling for under $10 US

Comment: See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/12803-find-replace.html

Answer (score 0):

> Run-time error '1004': Excel cannot access 'Documents' (the folder where my spreadsheet is)

It seems the following line of code gives the error message:

```
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...\Documents")
```

Make sure the specified folder exists on the disk. The user name can be different on each machine, so you may get such errors if you move your code to another machine.

So, I'd suggest copying the path and opening the folder manually.